# Facebook integration in android is not working when Facebook app is already installed

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, integration

I have integrated Facebook sdk in my android application. It works fine when I run it in the emulator which is not having Facebook app. It properly allows me to login but when I tried it in emulator and real device having Facebook app it just shows progress bar but does not login/logout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you didn't put in the right key hash in your app settings. Follow the getting started guide or use the quickstart guide to get the right key hash setup.

https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=android